# Stored procedure to notify amount of disk space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I am researching sql stored procedures. Currently one that checks amount of disk space on a server and then if under a certain amount(100MB) sends an email notification to users. I am just looking for some clarification on a bit of code below:

```
 SET @tableHTML = 'This is to notify you that Insufficient disk space encountered
                  in' + @DiskDrive + ' Drive' + '('+ + ')' + 'in SQLCircuit
```

I was just looking for someone to explain what '('++')' does. The full code is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetServerSpaceStatus]
 AS
 BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON

       DECLARE              @sErrorMessage       AS NVARCHAR(255)
       DECLARE              @lErrorMessageID     AS INT
       DECLARE              @lReturnCode         AS INT
       DECLARE              @sMessage            AS NVARCHAR(4000)   
       DECLARE              @lIdentity           AS INT
       DECLARE              @DiskDrive           AS NVARCHAR(100)
       DECLARE              @DiskSpace           AS INT
       DECLARE              @SUBJECTMESSAGE NVARCHAR(500)
       DECLARE              @tableHTML NVARCHAR(500)

BEGIN TRY

       --Declaring table variable for storing Disk space information
       DECLARE @DiskFreeSpace AS TABLE
       (
        Drive CHAR(1),
        MB_Free INT
       )
       --Inserting disk space availability details into table variable
       INSERT INTO @DiskFreeSpace
       EXEC xp_fixeddrives

       --Storing drive name and free space(in MB) in variable.
       --Creteria for insufficient disk space equal or less than 100 MB
       SELECT  @DiskDrive= Drive ,
               @DiskSpace = MB_Free
       FROM @DiskFreeSpace
       WHERE MB_Free < 100

SET @SUBJECTMESSAGE= 'Production Support Mail: Insufficent Disk Space in ' +
@DiskDrive + ' Drive in SQLCircuit Blogspot Server'
SET @tableHTML = 'This is to notify you that Insufficient disk space encountered
                  in' + @DiskDrive + ' Drive' + '('+ + ')' + 'in         SQLCircuit
Blogspot Server, Please take necessary action to avoid any further issues' + 
CHAR(4) + 'Thanks,' + CHAR(4) +'SQLCircuit Team'

      --Sending Mail       
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                     @recipients='sqlcircuit@gmail.com',   
                     @subject = @SUBJECTMESSAGE,   
                     @Profile_Name='sqlcircuit',  --Profile of SMTP Server 
                     @body =  @tableHTML,   
                     @body_format = 'HTML' ;

      SET @lReturnCode = 0

END TRY 
       BEGIN CATCH  
             --logging Error information
             INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorLog]
                      ([MessageID],[ErrorNumber],[ErrorSeverity],[ErrorState],
                      [ErrorProcedure],[ErrorLine],[ErrorMessage],[CreatedBy],
                      [CreatedDate])                    
             VALUES
            (1,ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-
            '),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE(),'',GETDATE())  

END CATCH 
       RETURN @lReturnCode
       SET NOCOUNT OFF           
END
```

Comment: Why would you do this in a stored procedure?  Why not a scheduled task or some other mechanism?

Comment: Hi, I've just been asked to do it as a stored procedure specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that this is a typo. Perhaps the original author had intended to insert the contents of a variable into the message at that point and simply forgot to do so.

SQL Server is interpreting the first `+` as the string concatenation operator, and the second `+` as the [unary plus](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174362%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) on the string that follows it. That operator is meant to apply only to numeric operands, but it's nonetheless allowed in this context. There's a statement from Microsoft on TechNet [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718176/concatenation-operator-not-working-properly) in which they state that it's a bug, but a benign one, and that they don't intend to fix it due to backwards compatibility concerns.

Comment: I was wondering, since an increment didn't seem to make any sense here. I know it is not extremely important to the running of the code, but I was thinking perhaps it is just the specific SQL circuit.